# Store each number in array

Tags: php

Hey guys I'm new in php and I'm trying to store the numbers from a input into a string, something like this.

let's say that the input stores the number 1234:

```
$input = 1234;
```

So I wan't to store a single digit and not the whole number in the array like:

```
$arr[0] = 1;
$arr[1] = 2;
$arr[2] = 3;
...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Well I just found how to do it, $input = '1234'; would do the job, so I can access to each element with $input[0]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

String split

```
$arr = str_split($input);
```

Comment: Be sure to accept the best answer it will get you more answers in future when you have an accepted answer rate, personally my favorite is Mark's.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe type casting would work. See below for sample code.

```
$input = 1234;
$arr = (string)$input;

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($arr); $i++) {
  echo $arr[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "1234";
$array = str_split($str);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Beat me to it, +1 for use of var_dump, PHP is full of functions and I didn't know about that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = (string)1234;
echo $input[2];
```

echo will output 3 -- that is the spot in the string/pseudo array represented by the array index 2